# how to change a variable from a module inside a module in a module... (confused)

Tags: python, object, module

I have a variable in my main module which is changed using another module, but I want to change the variable from my main module through another module. I'm new to programmering, so I actually don't really know how to explain this stuff - sorry if I'm asking a stupid question.

The program's hierarchy looks a bit like this:

Main

---Features

---Pygame_handling

------Features

I use the "Features" module to change a variable in the "Main". I do this simply by getting the defined variable from "Features". But when I change the variable through "Pygame_handling", it is not changed in the "Features" object created in the "Main" module.

Main.py

```
import Features
class Simulator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Features  = Features.Methods()
        self.variables = self.Features.dictionary

        self.PyObject  = Pygame_handling.Window()
```

Pygame_handling.py

```
import Features
class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Features = Features.Methods()
        dict = {"some":"dict"}
        self.Features.monitor_changes(dict)
```

Comment: You need to give an example of your actual code.

Comment: In your Window class you call a function self.Features.Methods()  but your Window class doesn't have a Features attribute.

Comment: I don't see how this code relates to your question.  Your two files don't share any objects.

Comment: I edited the Pygame_handling.py module now, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing those classes?
Usually when I need to do something like this I code it like:

**py1.py:**

```
class Test(object):
    def test_print(self):
        print 'Hi!'

TEST = Test()
```

**py2.py:**

```
from py1 import TEST
TEST.test_print()

# Adding new stuff to the TEST initialized class
TEST.new_var = 50
print TEST.new_var
#output: 50
```

So now you can just use the initialized class from on that module.

Comment: But I don't see how this allows my to change anything in the TEST object in py1.py through py2.py

Comment: Not sure what you mean then, in your code example you don't really make any changes to the Features module in your Pygame_handling.py, you call it's Methods() function in the Window class. In case you do, however, make changes there, remember that modules are executed only ONCE, and that's why I usually have a initialized class, that way you can change the elements on the class initialized in py1.py. That is usually called a Singleton, and is usually frowned upon, but in my opinion it has it's uses.